# Configurar Net Core Identity con una base de datos que ya tiene las tablas

Tags: asp.net-core

Tengo una db que se uso en un proyecto donde implementaban Identity de .net Framework, el caso es que tengo que rehacer todo el proyecto como una Api en Core y queria usar la db que ya tengo con las tablas de Identity.
Encontre un tutorial de como en base a una db existente agregarle identity de forma manual (con y sin migraciones) pero no encuentro nada sobre como hacerlo con las tablas ya creadas.
Cuando hago el sccafold con EF me trae las clases de todas las tablas ASPxxx pero no con el formato de identity sino como una clase comun y corriente.
Lo que hice hasta ahora es instalar el nugget de IdentityFramework, luego hice heredar al contes}xt de identity y agregue el service en startup pero no se como hacer para que las tablas me las pase al formato Identity.
Por ejemplo una de las tablas se ve asi:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

#nullable disable

namespace EB_API.Data
{
    public partial class AspNetUser
    {
        public AspNetUser()
        {
            AspNetUserClaims = new HashSet<AspNetUserClaim>();
            AspNetUserLogins = new HashSet<AspNetUserLogin>();
            AspNetUserRoles = new HashSet<AspNetUserRole>();
            Ogpedidos = new HashSet<Ogpedido>();
            OrdenDeCompras = new HashSet<OrdenDeCompra>();
        }

        public string Id { get; set; }
        public int? DistribuidorId { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public bool EmailConfirmed { get; set; }
        public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
        public string SecurityStamp { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public bool PhoneNumberConfirmed { get; set; }
        public bool TwoFactorEnabled { get; set; }
        public DateTime? LockoutEndDateUtc { get; set; }
        public bool LockoutEnabled { get; set; }
        public int AccessFailedCount { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public int? UserDataId { get; set; }

        public virtual Distribuidor Distribuidor { get; set; }
        public virtual UserDatum UserData { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<AspNetUserClaim> AspNetUserClaims { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<AspNetUserLogin> AspNetUserLogins { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<AspNetUserRole> AspNetUserRoles { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Ogpedido> Ogpedidos { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<OrdenDeCompra> OrdenDeCompras { get; set; }
    }
}
```